# Create an application GUI by Javafx

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, javafx

everyone.
My name is Nick, a totally newbie to Javafx. Recently, our team has been running a project and we would love making GUI by Javafx. I am being stuck at the moment. The following is what's in our imagination:

[image]

After reading some documentations, here what I've got:

[image]

I really appreciate if someone could help give me some hints to get things done. This is an academic project. Thanks so much for your valuable time.

Best Regards

Comment: Please ask specific questions. Whith what do you have problems?

Comment: Hi Puce, so sorry for my mistake. I've got 3 troubles here: First, My table has 3 columns instead of 2. Second, the buttons are supposedly on the left rather than at the bottom. Lastly, how to add words above my table.

Comment: The way StackOverflow works is if you have 3 troubles which are pretty unrelated, then ask 3 specific questions, one for each trouble and make each question self contained so it can be understood, the issue replicated and a solution provided.  I suggest that in each question you provide an FXML file which can be loaded into SceneBuilder and demonstrates only the one "trouble" that the question is asking about.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [`Scenebuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/jsbpub-user_guide.htm) tool. It is a WYSIWYG GUI editor provided especially for the purposes like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this links.. using this you don't want design manually.. with netbeans you can design just by drag and drop content what you want.

Scene builder is also good tool to design your system at a stretch.

[JavaFX Scene Builder
A Visual Layout Tool for JavaFX Applications](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen)

First of all take a look at this. so you can get through easily in javaFX.

[Java GUI Applications Learning Trail](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/matisse.html)

After looking all this.. then any problem occurs then ask here..

Thanks..

Comment: JavaFX Composer is for JavaFX 1.x and thus has no relevance anymore.