# How to turn my classes (Person, Student. Faculty and Staff) into GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface

please teach me how to convert the code into a interface. What should be done is that there is a person class which has a name, address, gender, and phone. then a student, faculty, staff class which inherits the person class. but the student has a course and major, faculty has a rank and research area, and staff has a position and an office

this is my person code
//Person.java

```
class Person{
private String myName;
private String myAddress;
private char myGender;
private int myPhone;

public Person()
{
myName = "";
myAddress = "";
myGender = 'N';
myPhone = 0;
}

public Person(String name, String address, char gender, int phone){
myName = name;
myAddress = address;
myGender = gender;
myPhone = phone;
} 

public String getName(){
return myName;
} 

public String getAddress()
{ 
return myAddress; 
} 

public char getGender() 
{ 
return myGender; 
} 

public int getPhone()
{
return myPhone;
}

public void setName(String name) 
{ 
myName = name; 
} 

public void setAddress(String address) 
{ 
myAddress = address; 
} 

public void setGender(char gender) 
{ 
myGender = gender; 
} 

public void setPhone(int phone)
{
myPhone = phone;
}

public String toString() 
{ 
return myName + ", address: " + myAddress + ", gender: " + myGender + ", phone: " + myPhone; 
} 
}
```

this is my student code
//Student.java

```
class Student extends Person 
{ 
private String myCourse;
private String myMajor;

public Student() 
{ 
super(); 

myCourse = ""; 
myMajor = ""; 
} 

public Student(String name, String address, char gender, int phone, 
             String course, String major)
{ 
super(name, address, gender, phone);

myCourse = course; 
myMajor = major; 
} 

public String getCourse() 
{ 
return myCourse; 
} 

public String getMajor() 
{ 
return myMajor; 
} 

public void setCourse(String course) 
{ 
myCourse = course; 
} 

public void setMajor(String major) 
{ 
myMajor = major; 
} 

public String toString() 
{ 
return super.toString() + ", course: " + myCourse + ", major: " + myMajor; 
} 
}
```

this is my faculty code
//Faculty.java

```
public class Faculty extends Person
{ 
private String myRank; 
private String myResearch;

public Faculty() 
{ 
super(); 

myRank = ""; 
myResearch = ""; 
}  

public Faculty(String name, String address, char gender, int phone, String rank, String research)
{
super(name, address, gender, phone); 

myRank = rank;
myResearch = research;
} 

public String getRank()
{
    return myRank;
}

public String getResearch()
{
return myResearch;
} 

public void setRank(String rank)
{
myRank = rank;
} 

public void setResearch(String research)
{
myResearch = research;
} 

public String toString() { 
    return super.toString() + ", rank: " + myRank + ", research: " + myResearch; 
} 
}
```

this is my staff code 
//Staff.java

```
public class Staff extends Person
{ 
private String myPosition; 
private String myOffice;

public Staff() 
{ 
super(); 

myPosition = ""; 
myOffice = ""; 
}  

public Staff(String name, String address, char gender, int phone, String position, String office)
{
super(name, address, gender, phone); 

myPosition = position;
myOffice = office;
} 

public String getPosition()
{
return myPosition;
}

public String getOffice()
{
return myOffice;
} 

public void setPosition(String position)
{
myPosition = position;
} 

public void setResearch(String office)
{
myOffice = office;
} 

public String toString() { 
return super.toString() + ", position: " + myPosition + ", office: " + myOffice; 
} 
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsVOm.jpg)

please teach me how to convert the code into a interface

Comment: This is *far* too broad for a Stack Overflow question, essentially what you're looking for is any tutorials on any given Java GUI framework/technology.  Fortunately, a quick Google search finds another very old Stack Overflow question which, while currently off-topic, has been preserved for posterity and may be a good place for you to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx

Answer (score 3):

Basicly these are just the Models that your application is going to use. You cannot create a user interface having just these Models, but you can make it yourself.

In Java, you have various libraries which help you to create GUI, for example [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/overview/jfxpub-overview.htm) or [Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) (not really recommended today).

When it comes to the project architecture, what you can use is a design pattern called [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

There are also other questions which consider basics of user interfaces in Java, which could help you:
[How to create a GUI in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118701/how-to-create-a-gui-in-java)
or
[Create an application GUI by Javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22248645/create-an-application-gui-by-javafx)

And if you are still unsure of which GUI library you should use, see this question:
[Java GUI frameworks. What to choose? Swing, SWT, AWT, SwingX, JGoodies, JavaFX, Apache Pivot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358775/java-gui-frameworks-what-to-choose-swing-swt-awt-swingx-jgoodies-javafx)